# Understanding proof that $d_n : H_n(S_*) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S_*'')$ is a homomorphism for a short exact sequence of complexes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, exact-sequence

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**

If $0 \rightarrow (S_*', \partial') \rightarrow ^i (S_*, \partial)^p \rightarrow (S''_*, \partial'') \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of complexes, then for each $n$ there is a homomorphism $d_n : H_n(S_*'') \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S_*')$ given by $\text{cls } z_n'' \mapsto \text{ cls } i^{-1}_{n-1} \partial_n p_n^{-1} z_n''$

And the proof is as follows:

> Suppose that $z_n'' \in Z_n''$ so $\partial''z'' = 0.$  **Since $p$ is surjective, we may lift $z''$ to $s_n \in S_n$** and then push down to $\partial s_n \in S_{n-1}.$ By commutativity, $\partial s_n \in \text{ker}(S_{n-1} \rightarrow S_{n-1}'') = \text{im } i$.  It follows that $i^{-1} \partial s_n$ makes sense; that is, there is a unique $s'_{n-1} \in S'_{n-1}$ with $is_{n-1}' = \partial s_n$.  Suppose we had lifted $z''$ to $\sigma_n \in S_n$.  Then the construction above yields $\sigma'_{n-1} \in S'_{n-1}.$
>
> We also know that $s_n - \sigma_n \in \text{ker } p = \text{im}(S'_n \rightarrow S_n)$, so there is $x'_n \in S'_n$ with $s'_{n-1} - \sigma'_{n-1} = \partial' x'_{n} \in B'_{n-1}$.  There is thus a well defined homomorphsim $Z''_n \rightarrow S'_{n-1}/B_{n-1}'$.  It is easy to see that this map sends $B''_n$ into $0$ and that $s'_{n-1} = i^{-1}\partial p^{-1}z''$ is a cycle.  Therefore the formula does give a map $H_n(S''_*) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S_*')$, as desired.

**Question 1:**  I don't understand what the author is doing in the first line of the proof with $p$.  The function $p: S_n \rightarrow S_n'$ is surjective which just implies all inverse image sets are nonempty.  Then what does he mean when he says "we may lift $z''$ to $s_n \in S_n$"?  Since the definition of $p^{-1}(z'') = \{s_n \in S_n :p(s_n) = z'' \}$, how can he just choose an arbitrary element of $p^{-1}(z'')$ and say that that's the inverse?  He, in the next few lines of the same paragraph, then does the same with when he supposes that $p^{-1}(z'') = \sigma_n$.  Is he using a different definition for $p^{-1}$ than the inverse image?

**Question 2**:  Supposing the above question is answered, how does the map send $B_n''$ into $0$ and how is $s_{n-1}' = i^{-1} \partial p^{-1} z''$ a cycle?

Answer (score 1):

To complement Noel's answer:

If $z_n'' \in Z_n''$, then because of the surjectivity of $p$ there exists some $s_n \in S_n$ such that $p(s_n)=z_n''$. Now this $s_n$ may not be unique, but this doesn't matter, because we're not trying to define a function on this step. For now we're just seeing if it makes sense to talk about picking an element in $(i^{-1} \partial p^{-1} )(z'')$, this is, if there exists some  $a \in S'_{n-1}$ such that $( p \partial ^{-1}i )(a) = z''$, and this is what the first lines of the proof deal with.

Now we define $D: Z''_n \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S_*')$ as the map sending a cycle $z_n''$ to $[a]$, the homology class of the $a$ whose existence we just proved in the first part of the proof. To prove that this $D$ is actually a function, we have to make sure that it doesn't send the same $z''_n \in Z''_n$ to two different objects in $H_{n-1}(S_*')$. To prove this, let $z''_n \in Z''_n$ and suppose that $\sigma_n , s_n \in p^{-1}(z''_n)$. The first paragraph of the proof shows that in that case there exist unique $s'_{n-1}, \sigma'_{n-1} \in S'_{n-1}$ with $is_{n-1}' = \partial s_n$ and $i\sigma'_{n-1} = \partial \sigma_n$. In the second paragraph we do the following:

Since $s_{n}, \sigma_{n} \in p^{-1}(z''_n)$, then:

$$p(s_{n}- \sigma_{n})= p(s_{n})- p(\sigma_{n})=z''_n - z''_n = 0 \implies s_n - \sigma_n \in \ker p$$

By exactness, $\ker p = \text{im}(S'_n \rightarrow S_n)$, so there's $x'_n \in S'_n$ with $i(x'_n)=s_n - \sigma_n$ Pushing $x'_n$ down with $\partial '$ and using conmutativity, we get $s'_{n-1} - \sigma'_{n-1} = \partial ' x'_n \in B'_{n-1}$, so $[s'_{n-1} - \sigma'_{n-1}]=[\partial ' x'_n] = [0] \in H_{n-1}(S_*')$, and therefore the difference $s_n - \sigma_n$ of the two different objects $s_n, \sigma _n \in p^{-1}(z''_n)$ is sent to zero on homology, so $s_n$ and $\sigma _n$ go to the same object in $H_{n-1}(S_*')$ and thus our $D$ is indeed a function.

Noel already showed that whatever your choice of $(i^{-1} \partial p^{-1} )(z'')$ is, it is a cycle. To see that the induced map $H_n(S''_*) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S_*')$ is well defined it remains to show that it is independent of the representatives. To see this, let $c \in S''_n$ and  $c' = c + \partial '' \ \overline{c}$,  for some $\overline c \in S''_{n+1}$. We want to make sure that $D$ sends both to the same object. $p_*$ is surjective, so there exist $b \in S_{n}$ with $p_n b = c$ and  $\overline{b} \in S_{n+1}$ with $p_{n+1} \overline{b} = \overline{c}$. We then have that $p^{-1}(c')= b' = b + \partial \overline{b} \in S_n$ is sent by $\partial$ to $\partial b + \partial \partial \overline{b} = \partial b$, so $c'$ gets sent to the same $a$ as $c$ by $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Lifting $z''$ to $S_n$ means choosing *some* $s_n \in S_n$ so that $p(s_n) = z''$, this cannot be done canonically since in general there are many choices of $s_n$ for each $z''$ but it all becomes well defined in homology.

As for your second question we know that $i(s'_{n-1}) = \partial s_n$ (since $p^{-1}z'' = s_n$) so $\partial i(s'_{n-1}) = \partial \partial s_n = 0$ but $i$ is a chain map so commutes with boundary operators, $i(\partial s'_{n-1}) = 0$ aswell which means that $\partial s'_{n-1} = 0$ since $i$ has zero kernel (is injective).

Hope this answered your question! The notation $p^{-1}z''$ is super confusing and is not widely used, so don't worry about trying to make sense of it, just know that $p^{-1}z'' = s_n$ iff $p(s_n) = z''$.

Comment: I'm not understanding, can you elaborate more on this?  You said "this can't be done canonically" but then "it all becomes well defined", can you expand on that?  Are you saying that he's not taking the inverse image but he's using a function $p_{s_n}^{-1}$ (that he's calling $p^{-1}$) such that $p_{s_n}^{-1}(z'')$ is defined as $s_n$?

Comment: I'm saying that whatever choices you make for $s_n$ and $s'_{n-1}$ it turns out that all choices you can make for $s'_{n-1}$ all become equal in the homology group so you can just make any choice that satisfies the requirements and it won't make a difference since we aim to define a map $H_n(S'') \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S')$.

Comment: And $p^{-1}$ isn't a function, it is a multivalued function. The "function" $S''_n \rightarrow S'_{n-1}$ isn't a function either, it is a multivalued function which becomes single valued in homology, does that make more sense?

Comment: What definition of $p^{-1}$ as a multivalued function is Rotman using here?

Comment: He doesn't consider $p^{-1}$ as a multivalued function, he just assumes that $p^{-1}$ is some singlue valued function satisying $p \circ p^{-1}$ I guess. You should stop worrying about what $p^{-1}$ really means since it's not important to understand the material.

Comment: What do you mean by "satisfying $p \circ p^{-1}$"?

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be "satisfying $p \circ p^{-1} = id$"

Comment: If $p^{-1}$ is a single valued function from $S'' \rightarrow S$, how is it guaranteed to be a homomorphism?

Comment: It's not a homomorphism. But the map you end up defining $H_n(S'') \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S')$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Why is $p^{-1}$ guaranteed to be a function?  Why can you just assume that $p^{-1}$ is well defined given the only information you have about it is $(1.) p \circ p^{-1} = \text{id}$ and $(2.) p^{-1}(z'') = s_n$?  Why is it the case that $p^{-1}(w'')$ is guaranteed to be single valued for other values $w''$ in $Z_n''$?